# graph traverse with oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, graph-traversal

I have a table which each record in that represent an edge between to nodes in a graph. The from_node and to_node columns represent the ID of each node in the graph. The edge table structure is similar to below:

| from_node | to_node |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |

Now I want to find all connected sub-graph base on the above table. How can I traverse the graph and label each sub-graph with a unique number? I need an output as below table:

| node | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |

Comment: what do you expect as output in the given example input?

Comment: I update the input table and add some rows in it, then I added my expected results for the input table.

Comment: Your example is very simple and can be solved with simple recursive query (search this site for examples). Now if you have more complex graphs, your better look at the [graph engine in Oracle DB](https://www.oracle.com/database/graph/)

Comment: Thanks, I need that simple query :)